# Save value datapicker Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i have code JS

```
$(function () {
$("#from").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

});

Code HTML
`<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />`

I want save value in text each chose, now went i chose date it disable went i choose, please help me

Comment: which datepicker are u using??can u create a jsfiddle

Comment: Cannot figure out your exact problem, please give a proper explanation and if possible a demo jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** so that you can choose past date: http://jsfiddle.net/vfnjQ/ or http://jsfiddle.net/eff4J/

I reckon your issue was, old dates were becoming **disable** like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eff4J/1/

To enable dates, set the `startdate` option for the `datepicker.

- *Options/events/Methods API documentation here* http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

hope rest fits your cause `:)`

**code**

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        startDate:'01/01/2000', 
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
          //  $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        startDate:'01/01/2000',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
          //  $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But when i klick search value in texbox datetime disable